# Blackberry java BIS-Push client sample

Tags: blackberry, java-me, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-push

I want to implement a simple blackberry push client application for studying purposes. I tested the sample given by RIM successfully. I found great simplified client sample java codes from the "[Simplified BIS-Push client sample](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/BlackBerry-Push-Development/Simplified-BIS-Push-client-sample/ta-p/693857)" but I don't know how to integrate this with a Blackberry application created in Eclipse. Can any one please help me how to use these codes and how to get the output ?

Comment: check this - http://rincethomas.blogspot.in/search/label/Push%20Notification

Comment: Thanks for the comment and it is really helpful, but it is bit complicated because I'm a beginner. can you please tell me how to run the application provided here supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/BlackBerry-Push-Development/Simplified-BIS-Push-client-sample/ta-p/693857

Comment: that two files contains the registration and listening of push message code.

Comment: can't we get pushed messages from that codes ??

Comment: when i'm running your codes error comes up saying An internal error occurred during: "Packaging push_msg".
java.lang.NullPointerException
why is that ??

Comment: you got push credentials from blackberry ?

Comment: yep all are fine I tested sample application successfully. Can you please tell me how to get the output from two classes provided in support forum it is easy for me :)

Comment: create a demo app, then push the PushAgent screen class for registering the push message, at the same time, run the PushMessageReader class as background thread.

Comment: for background thread, use alternate entry point

Comment: Please help still having the same problem. I don't know how to use those two java classes

Comment: Please give me a solution for this problem 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17079130/blackberry-java-show-recieved-push-message